# I want to "tab dock" any app to side (or top) of Desktop (in Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, tabs, dock, window-manager

I am looking for something a bit different than any "dock" style app I have tried.

What I am looking for is something a bit like the awesome "stick" application

http://iwonderdesigns.com/project_overview/stick/

only that is able to put ANY window into a tab.

The effect would be similar to when OneNote is docked to the side of the desktop, except that only a certain tabbed area (rather than the entire side of the desktop) would activate.

Or, to put it another way, it would work kind of like a regular dock, except that the dock items would be little tabs, attached to any screen edge, that I would click on, and the tab would stay attached to the window so it would shrink back when I clicked on it again.  (Alternately, a tabbed application could be made to "auto-hide")

Anybody know of anyone working on anything like this?

Comment: I'd love this too. I guess it doesn't really exist though :(
This gets close - http://winsplit-revolution.com/home

Comment: That app is awesome!

Comment: Maybe http://windowtabs.com is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I tried [Preme for windows 7](http://www.premeforwindows.com/), it is  pretty complete by now.

[image]

Comment: I just installed this and I'm really not sure how this is a solution to the question. There seem to be some good features, but no docking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just found [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap).  Not exactly what you want, but pretty neat.